# В чем разница между папками, составляющими проект Visual C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

В проекте по умолчанию есть 3 папки: заголовочные файлы, файлы ресурсов, файлы исходного кода. Есть ли между ними разница, если в любой папке можно создать любые доступные элементы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас на диске куча разных папок, в любую из них можно поместить любые файлы. Какая между ними разница? Это надо владельца спрашивать, он же их зачем-то завел.

Папки VS ничем от дисковых не отличаются - это просто средство как-то логически разделить большой набор файлов. VS создает некий стандартный набор папок, но вы совершенно не обязаны их использовать. Их можно удалить, или переименовать, или дополнить. Например, в большой MFC программе может оказаться удобнее не сваливать все исходники в одну папку, а все заголовки в другую, а завести папки Frames, Documents, Views, Dialogs, и так далее.